# Matlab Z transform coefficient extraction

Tags: matlab

Hi I have a z transform function
3/z + 5/z^2 + 6/z^3 + 1

How would I extract the coefficients from this equation? I have tried using coeffs and it says it is not a polynomial.

I would like the answer to come out as
[3 5 6 1]

Comment: Are you using the symbolic math toolbox?

Comment: Sorry I am fairly new to Matlab so I'm not sure if I am using the symbol math toolbox. I did however create the z as a symbolic variable syms z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a different variable `x=1/z` and find the coefficients of the polynomial `3x+5x^2+gx^3+1`:

```
syms x
coeffs(subs(3/z+5/z^2+6/z^3+1,z,1/x))
```